# Jest tests keep failing

Tags: reactjs, babel-jest

I am trying to unit test my React application and when i run npm run jest, it fails saying

```
Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /node_modules/babel-preset-react/lib/index.js
```

Tried doing npm install of @babel/preset-env and @babel/preset-react

please find my jest,babel config in package.json

```
"jest": {
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/test/jest/mocks/fileMock.js",
    "^.+\\.(css|styl)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
    "<rootDir>/test/jest/config.js"
  ],
  "snapshotSerializers": [
    "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
  ],
  "setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/test/jest/enzyme.js"
  ],
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/(node_modules)/"
  ]
},
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "dynamic-import-node"
  ]
},
"dependencies": {
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0"
}
```

Please advise to get jest tests up and running and to get rid of the error in the node_modules